# How to use Docker Desktop (Windows)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, dockerfile, docker-desktop

I have just installed Docker Desktop on Win11. I am following the tutorials that are included within the Docker Desktop App itself and which are presented upon first installing Docker Desktop under the "Learning Center" menu. They fail to answer some very basic questions, like:

*Does Docker Desktop require that I install git separately, or is it included?*
[image: git included or required?]

Secondly, it assumes I know where to find the Dockerfile.

*I have no idea where it is - where is it?*

[image: Where is the Dockerfile located?]

*Thirdly, if I pull an image down using Docker Desktop, where does it store the image/files locally? If I run this command in the CLI, do I need to be in a DOS/PS prompt, or do I need to run it from within the WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) shell? And what directory should I be in when I run it?*

[image]

*Fourthly, where is the compose.yaml file located?*

[image]

*Fifthly, do Docker project folders need to be located somewhere specifically relative to the Docker Desktop application itself for docker commands to work properly, or can I create Docker project folders anywhere that suits my folder management scheme?*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get better answers if you provide more information on which tutorial you are following, what did you tried to do to solve/learn about your problem, etc. Still, with the given information:

1. The first step is to download the sample application to your own machine so you can look at Dockerfile or docker-compose and understand how to use Docker. If you do not have git installed on your machine you should do so, then use `git clone` command to clone the sample application repository to your machine. Check out git documentation if you are not familiar: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone
2. With the sample application installed, you should see Dockerfile and docker-compose inside the project directory.
3. Docker layers and images are stored at `C:\ProgramData\docker`. Check out this page for more detailed information: https://github.com/docker/getting-started-app
4. You can create docker projects everywhere, the commands connect to the Docker engine with api and create the images/containers in its own file system. See for more info: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/overview/#docker-architecture

Comment: These are the built in tutorials within the Docker Desktop app itself. Thanks.

Comment: I added context to my question for the benefit of others. I did find the answers after some 'duckducking' and poking around, but your answer is fairly accurate.